# JSF webApplication - glassfish server server encountered an internal error

Tags: mysql

in brief:

`[Problem in glassfish Admin console when I try to Create a new JDBC Connection Pools]`

can someone help me please solve this problem :

firstly, I want to develop a `JSF` application on `Netbeans IDE 8.1`

when I fill the page of creating a new `JDBC Connection Pools` glassfish console throws this  Exception :

```
type : Exception report

message :Internal Server Error

description : The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception : 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

note : The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
```

see this pictures for more informations :
[glassfish Admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECpqa.png)

[domain.XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Byj6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem in this tutorial : 
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted-pf-screencast.html